requests Python выдает не полную информацию
есть код
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
url = 'https://map.minecraft-galaxy.ru/#0/0/12/0/43/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print(soup)
players = soup.find_all('div',class_='players-ui')
print(players)

print(players) выводит []
так как ничего не было найдено
Код заходит на онлайн карту игры и пытается забрать список игроков, но вместо того чтобы забрать список но
он ничего не выдает. print(soup) выдает страницу но там подозрительно мало данных и нет ни какого списка.
Пытался так же залогиниться на форуме - 0 результата
искал в гугле какие нибудь варианты которые смогут помочь но ничего не нашел

Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?
